# what, in the context of LaTeX, is the meaning of "template"?

Tags: discussion, tagging

the purpose of this question is to improve user documentation so that we don't get questions when a user tries to process an unaltered template.

at AMS, we distribute "author packages", each of which includes a template to get an author started.  this template contains bare-bones code -- such as `\include{}` and `\includeonly{}` -- that is meant to be filled in, along with `%`ed comments saying how to use the code.

these templates can't be processed without change, but some authors try to do so anyhow, resulting in confusing errors.  (for `\include{}`, the error is that the `.tex` file can't be found.)  clearly, our understanding of what "template" means isn't the same as that of (some) authors.

in the context of LaTeX, what do you think "template" means:

- a basic outline that requires some modification to be processable?
- a processable example that can be modified to suit the author's needs?
- something else entirely?

Comment: I understand under "template" a form of example file which shows how to do the real document. It might be compilable (and better should be), but doesn't have to. I however, encountered a lot of people (mostly beginners) which confuse a class with a template.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an attempt to define 'template' but merely a description of how it is used on the site. It might serve as a starting point for this discussion.

- See [Do we need both {documentclass} and {templates}?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1711/do-we-need-both-documentclass-and-templates/1712#1712) for a discussion of the difference between document clases and templates.
- There is a tag for templates, [templates](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/templates), which has 563 posts. Its [tag wiki](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tags/templates/info) quotes the meta discussion mentioned above. Skimming through these templates seems to have the meaning of a basic outline or general example that is easily adaptable to the user's needs.

Comment: actually, i had already read that post (but failed to mention it), so thanks for the reminder.  it (and the most recent question from a confused author) is what prompted me to finally ask my question.  i've done some work in the standards arena, and there it is de rigueur to first give a very explicit definition for all terminology.  i was hoping i wouldn't have to go to that extreme (many authors don't even read documentation, and admit it proudly), but if the majority understanding of "template" is "example", then i guess it will be necessary, if probably fruitless.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Your two suggestion for what it means seems to correspond to how it is used on the site. It is how I understand it too but my comprehension of the word may be misguided. I agree that a good definition would be preferable.